# Why would this Entity Framework routine skip insert for some children?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following method which inserts a row into `ADGroup` and then inserts a row into child table `GroupExtension`:

```
    public async Task AddADGroupsAsync(List<ADGroup> adGroups)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            EntityFramework.ADGroup dbADGroup;
            EntityFramework.ADGroup dbADGroupInsert;
            GroupExtension dbGroupExtension;

            using (var dbContext = new SecurityAPIEntities())
            {
                foreach (var adGroup in adGroups)
                {
                    dbADGroup = new EntityFramework.ADGroup
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        Name = adGroup.Guid
                    };

                    dbADGroupInsert = dbContext.ADGroups.Add(dbADGroup);
                    dbGroupExtension = new GroupExtension
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                        UpdatedDateTime = DateTime.Now
                    };
                    dbADGroupInsert.GroupExtensions.Add(dbGroupExtension);
                }
                await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is that this code is inserting 8914 rows into `ADGroup`, but only 8676 rows into `GroupExtension`. This seems like a pretty basic operation so I'm not sure why it's failing on a small number of child inserts. I think that this code may have been working when I had the `SaveChangesAsync()` inside of the foreach loop instead of after it.

Comment: Though it doesn't answer your question, what if you added the child property from within the parent property?  `dbADGroup = new EntityFramework.ADGroup { Id = Guid.NewGuid(),Name = adGroup.Guid, GroupExtension = new GroupExtension{attributes from adding new group extension}}` - does it behave the same?

Comment: What investigation have toy done? Have you checked to see which parent records lack a child and if there's anything common among them? Have you debugged/traced to see if the code behaves in any unexpected ways as it executes?  You really do need to do what you can for yourself first, before posting here.

Comment: if I move "await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();" to the location after each iteration in the foreach loop then no records get skipped so not sure why putting it out the outside of the foreach loop causes records to get skipped.  maybe it has something to do with a large result set (8500 rows)